# How to load a .dataframe file on file system using pickle in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

When executing the following code:

```
features_df = pickle.loads(open( "features.dataframe", "rb" ))
```

where `features.dataframe` is the filename,
I get the following error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the built-in [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html#pandas.read_pickle)?

Comment: New to this, trying out a sample, an example would really help.

Comment: @user3169748 - `df = pd.read_pickle('features.dataframe')` does not work?

Comment: it worked.... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) has quite [a few ways](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#input-output) to read data from storage.

From the comments you know you can use [`pandas.read_pickle()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html#pandas.read_pickle) as simply as:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('features.dataframe')
```

Comment: this only returns a list, how do you get a dataframe from it